# Matlab simulink c code generation

Tags: matlab, simulink

I would like to import an existing C code (or any other text) into my generated code by Matlab simulink.I have some tasks that made in C,but in the future i want to develop in matlab.I work in simulink,and I can compile the models,but I want to use some special function what I previously wrote in C (because of pointer etc.).

**The problem is that** I don't know how to put in these texts into the model,and after the code generation these texts stay in the original format,and placed in the expected line.

[image]
And what I would like:

[image]

Comment: So you want that the "the C functions"  block is generated with inputs and outputs in Simulink?

Comment: "The C functions" block is an independent c code.For example in this block I want to init the serial communication,write log files,calls other already written functions ect.Of course i can copy-paste these parts  manually in the builded code,but i would like to integrate these in a subsystem or in a  block,and if a put this block in the simulink,after the build the functions there will be there.

Comment: But, if the block has no influence in the simulink system, why do you need it there

Comment: See documentation for integrating legacy code in code genertion. https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/integrating-existing-c-functions-into-simulink-models-with-the-legacy-code-tool.html

Comment: @AnderBiguri 
Because I have to test variables,that are in specified memory adress(other C tasks write these variables).For example  before I use my generated code by simulink,I have to test these variables,but they aren't global,so I can use pointers.I have already written this bit test function,and I would like to paste this into my simulink.I know that the matlab can't understand this function,so I have a "text block" what is ignored by the matlab's compiler,and just paste the content of the "text box" into the generated code.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the [S-Function Builder](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/sfunctionbuilder.html). It allows one to create C code blocks, which get compiled with the model run. If using Code Generator, it gets inserted into generated code.

I generally use it to call functions from my external code or libraries, as in some [Raspberry Pi Driver blocks](http://engineer.john-whittington.co.uk/2015/06/simulink-raspberry-pi-driver-blocks/) I created.

It generates .c, .h and .mex files for each block and is quite clunky but does work!

BTW: If it's just to use an external pointer, you can happily use ImportedPointer/ExportedPointer for this. I find this handy for variables between generated code and container.